# Dependency Injection on a Blazor page compared to a controller's constructor

Tags: c#, blazor-server-side

I'm working on a new application and I opted to go with Blazor Server Side. I have the existing backend setup and am trying to replace the UI project only. I have a registry for all the services and this registry is used in both API and Blazor UI project:

```
public class DependencyContainer
{

    public static void RegisterServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        #region Domain InMemoryBus MediatR

        services.AddScoped<IMediatorHandler, InMemoryBus>();

        #endregion

        #region Domain Handlers

        services.AddScoped<IRequestHandler<RadarCreateCommand, bool>, RadarProjectCommandHandler>();

        #endregion

        #region Application Layer

        services.AddScoped<IRadarProjectService, RadarProjectService>();
        //services.AddScoped<IContactService, ContactService>();
        //services.AddScoped<ICategoryService, CategoryService>();
        //services.AddScoped<ISubCategoryService, SubCategoryService>();

        #endregion

        #region Infrastructure/Data Layer

        services.AddScoped<IPlaygroundBiRepository, PlaygroundBiRepository>();
        //services.AddScoped<IContactRepository, ContactRepository>();
        //services.AddScoped<ICategoryRepository, CategoryRepository>();
        //services.AddScoped<ISubCategoryRepository, SubCategoryRepository>();

        services.AddScoped<DesignTrackerContext>();
        services.AddScoped<PlaygroundBiContext>();

        #endregion

    }

}
```

In my Blazor project, I have the reference to the registry project and am calling this method in 'Startup.cs' as:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddRazorPages();
        ...
        services.AddMediatR(typeof(Startup));
        services.RegisterAutoMapper();

        RegisterServices(services);
    }
```

Now, on my page, I want to show a list of Projects. There is a service that will expose all projects non-entity POCOs. The page is setup like so:

```
@page "/projects"
@using DesignTracker.Application.Interfaces
@using DesignTracker.Application.ViewModels

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row my-4">
        <div class="col-12">
            <TelerikGrid Data="@allProjects" Height="550px" FilterMode="@GridFilterMode.FilterMenu"
                         Sortable="true" Pageable="true" PageSize="20" Groupable="true"
                         EditMode="@GridEditMode.Inline">
                <GridColumns>
                    <GridColumn Field="Id" Title="Id" Width="100px" Editable="false" Groupable="false" />
                    <GridColumn Field="Date">
                        <Template>
                            @((context as RadarProjectViewModel).LastUpdateTime?.ToString("dddd, dd MMM yyyy"))
                        </Template>
                    </GridColumn>
                    <GridColumn Field="Name" />
                    <GridColumn Field="Department" />
                    <GridColumn Field="Summary" />
                    <GridCommandColumn>
                        <GridCommandButton Command="Save" Icon="@IconName.Save" ShowInEdit="true">Update</GridCommandButton>
                        <GridCommandButton Command="Edit" Icon="@IconName.Edit" Primary="true">Edit</GridCommandButton>
                        <GridCommandButton Command="Delete" Icon="@IconName.Delete">Delete</GridCommandButton>
                        <GridCommandButton Command="Cancel" Icon="@IconName.Cancel" ShowInEdit="true">Cancel</GridCommandButton>
                    </GridCommandColumn>
                </GridColumns>
                <GridToolBar>
                    <GridCommandButton Command="Add" Icon="@IconName.Plus" Primary="true">Add Project</GridCommandButton>
                </GridToolBar>
            </TelerikGrid>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    private readonly IRadarProjectService _service;
    private IEnumerable<RadarProjectViewModel> allProjects;
}
```

If I follow the WeatherService example that is shipping with Blazor templates, I do not see IoC in action because there is a method that is called in the `OnInitializedAsync()` that actually initializes the forecasts:

```
List<WeatherForecast> forecasts { get; set; }

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    await GetForecasts();
}

async Task GetForecasts()
{
    forecasts = await ForecastService.GetForecastListAsync(DateTime.Now);
}
```

From my MVC and Asp.Net Core experience, all I needed to do was create backing interfaces for the services I required and create a loaded constructor and the DI engine would inject the initialized objects at runtime.

How is this possible in Blazor's `code{ ... }`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To apply dependency injection directly on the blazor page use `@inject` directive.

#### Example

`.razor` page:

```cs
@page "/"
@using YourServiceNamespace

@inject IYourService yourService // Here injecting dependency

<div>/*some html here*/</div>

@code 
{
    public string[] ArrayOfStrings => yourService.GetArrayOfStrings(); 
}
```

`Startup.cs` file:

```cs
services.AddScoped<IYourService, YourService>();
```

Blazor will automatically receive your service from application environment and injects it directly into page so you can use it like from plain csharp code.

Comment: I completely forgot there was an inject directive... 

Comment: @HassanGulzar if you think this answer fully answered on your question please be kindly mark this post as an answer for community in future